# agda-mode not installing onto any version of emacs

Tags: emacs, agda, agda-mode, agda-stdlib

Agda Mode, the tool used to aid in the discovery of proofs alongside the program initialised by the `agda-setup` command is not working. I have tried this through `sudo` usage and have the same error.

The error I get, is below:

```
lukemccartney@Lukes-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo agda-mode setup
Password:
FAILED: emacs --batch --user '' --eval '(with-temp-file "/tmp/askEmacs2284-0" (insert (expand-file-name user-init-file)))'
Exception: emacs: rawSystem: posix_spawnp: permission denied (Permission denied)
Executable emacs at: (not found)
PATH:
  - /opt/local/bin
  - /opt/local/sbin
  - /Users/lukemccartney/.cargo/bin
  - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
  - /usr/local/bin
  - /usr/bin
  - /bin
  - /usr/sbin
  - /sbin
  - /usr/local/Cellar/llvm@12
  - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
  - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
  - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
  - /opt/X11/bin
  - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
  - /Library/TeX/texbin
  - /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
  - /Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
  - /usr/local/share/dotnet
  - ~/.dotnet/tools
  - /usr/local/go/bin
  - /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
  - /Users/lukemccartney/.cabal/bin
  - /Users/lukemccartney/.ghcup/bin
```

I have tried installing via `sudo` I have also tried to move a version of emacs to the locations listed in the error but keep getting the same error.

Comment: Please add the output of `emacs --version`.

Comment: lukemccartney@Lukes-MacBook-Pro ~ % emacs --version
zsh: command not found: emacs

Answer (score 0):

`agda-mode` that you're attempting to `setup` is an [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs) mode for Agda, meaning you need to have Emacs installed to be able to use the mode, which you don't have according to

> `emacs --version zsh: command not found: emacs`

So make sure to install `Emacs` and put it on your `$PATH`.

Note that some other editors like Atom and Vim also have an Agda mode.

You can find information about the Emacs Agda mode as well as references to the other modes [here](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/emacs-mode.html).

Comment: I have managed to get Agda Mode installed and working with standard Agda (not Aquamacs).